How can I prevent sediment from clogging my yard drain?
My side-of-the street is on the bottom of the hill and I get a lot of dirt / sediment flowing downhill into my yard, which clogs my two drain(s) to the street (which is backed up - another problem!).
With current weather patterns, the situation is only getting worse year over year. We need the drain in the backyard, but I need a reasonable-looking solution to keep the dirt and foliage out while letting bursts of rainwater into the system.
A quick search has revealed linen or coconut fiber covers, but alas they seem more for industrial size drains and I'm worried about them washing off(?) in the event a back-flow filter takes effect.
A picture of the drains look like:



Sediment accumulation is dependent on land cover.  If there are areas upstream that are not stabilized, you'll get more sediment (and those areas will get erosion).  You don't say how large your property is, so I'm going to assume you don't have access to those areas—though you could certainly ask the property owners to put some cover (vegetated or mechanical, like mulch) on, and that would reduce the amount of sediment reaching your inlets.
As to what you can do yourself, assuming the above is not possible, it depends how fast you need those inlets to drain.  You could install a storm drain sediment filter, which is basically a geotextile basket that goes under the grate—there are various designs out there.  Or you could install an external filter, of which there are several designs.  Some use concrete block and gravel, but they're harder to clean than encircling the inlet with plain silt fence or filter sock.
